# Using a Class Library for ASP.NET Membership Provider with MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

I am attempting to use the ASP.NET Membership Provider with a MySQL database with mixed success. My solution currently contains an ASP.NET MVC project that has been configured to use MySQL and another project that handles all calls to the database in which I also want to handle membership functions such as creating and validating users.

Both projects have MS .NET EnityFramework v6.1.3, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework v2.2.1 and MySql.Data.Entity v6.9.7 installed.

I configured the ASP.NET project as per the instructions at http://k16c.eu/2014/10/12/asp-net-identity-2-0-mariadb/. My "web.config" is configured as follows;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<configuration> 
    <configSections> 
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" /> 
    </configSections> 
    <connectionStrings> 
        <remove name="LocalMySqlServer" /> 
        <add name="LocalMySqlServer" 
            connectionString="Server=localhost; Database=rb-web; Uid=root; Pwd=password; Convert Zero Datetime=True; Allow User Variables=True;" 
            providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" /> 
    </connectionStrings> 
    <system.web> 
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" /> 
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" /> 
    </system.web> 
    <entityFramework> 
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"> 
        <parameters> 
            <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" /> 
        </parameters> 
        </defaultConnectionFactory> 
        <providers> 
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" /> 
            <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" /> 
        </providers> 
    </entityFramework> 
    <system.data> 
        <DbProviderFactories> 
            <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" /> 
            <add name="MySQL Data Provider" 
                invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" 
                description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" 
                type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" /> 
        </DbProviderFactories> 
    </system.data> 
</configuration>
```

The instructions at http://k16c.eu/2014/10/12/asp-net-identity-2-0-mariadb/ required creating two new classes, ApplicationUser.cs and ApplicationContext.cs however these were basically replicating the code in IdentityModels.cs which was already included in my project. The identity model code is;

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using MySql.Data.Entity;

namespace RB.Client.Models
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    [DbConfigurationType(typeof(MySqlEFConfiguration))]
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext() : base("LocalMySqlServer", throwIfV1Schema: false) { }
        public ApplicationDbContext(string connStringName) : base(connStringName, throwIfV1Schema: false) { }
        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            // Primary keys can easily get too long for MySQL's (InnoDB's) stupid 767 bytes limit.
            // The following lines rewrite the generation to keep those columns "short" enough.
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
                .Property(c => c.Name)
                .HasMaxLength(128)
                .IsRequired();

            // Declare the table name here, otherwise IdentityUser will be created.
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .ToTable("AspNetUsers")
                .Property(c => c.UserName)
                .HasMaxLength(128)
                .IsRequired();
        }
    }
}
```

Once these changes were made I ran the Enable-Migrations from Package Manager Console and modified the Configuration.cs class as follows;

```
namespace RB.Client.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<RB.Client.Models.ApplicationDbContext>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
        }

        protected override void Seed(RB.Client.Models.ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

I then ran the Add-Migration "Initial" and Update-Database command from the Package Manager Console which created the aspnetroles, aspnetuserclaims, aspnetuiserlogins, aspnetuserroles and aspnetusers tables in MySQL.

I then use the following code in my persistence project;

```
public UserDto RegisterUser(UserDto user) 
{ 
    var appUser = Membership.CreateUser(user.Email, user.Password); 
}
```

Which raises the exception;

"Unable to initialize provider. Missing or incorrect schema." 
"MySql.Web at MySql.Web.Common.SchemaManager.CheckSchema(String connectionString, NameValueCollection config) 
at MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider.Initialize(String name, NameValueCollection config) 
at System.Web.Configuration.ProvidersHelper.InstantiateProvider(ProviderSettings providerSettings, Type providerType)"

However, if I add the following entries to the "web.config";

```
<system.web>
    <roleManager defaultProvider="MySQLRoleProvider">
        <providers>
            <remove name="MySQLRoleProvider" />
            <add name="MySQLRoleProvider"
                 type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLRoleProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
                 applicationName="/RBWeb"
                 description="RB Role Provider"
                 connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer"
                 writeExceptionsToEventLog="True"
                 autogenerateschema="True"
                 enableExpireCallback="False" />
        </providers>
    </roleManager>

    <membership defaultProvider="MySQLMembershipProvider">
        <providers>
            <remove name="MySQLMembershipProvider" />
            <add name="MySQLMembershipProvider"
                 type="MySql.Web.Security.MySQLMembershipProvider, MySql.Web, Version=6.9.7.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d"
                 applicationName="/RbWeb"
                 description="RB Membership Provider"
                 connectionStringName="LocalMySqlServer"
                 writeExceptionsToEventLog="True"
                 autogenerateschema="True"
                 enableExpireCallback="False"
                 enablePasswordRetrieval="False"
                 enablePasswordReset="True"
                 requiresQuestionAndAnswer="False"
                 requiresUniqueEmail="True"
                 passwordFormat="Hashed"
                 maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
                 minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
                 minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="1"
                 passwordAttemptWindow="10"
                 passwordStrengthRegularExpression="" />
        </providers>
    </membership>

    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

The user is successfully created and a System.Web.Security.MembershipUser object is returned. However the call has now generated a number of new tables in the database, my_aspnet_users, my_aspnet_roles, etc along with all of the tables for profiles, personalisation, and session management even though these options weren't included in the web.config settings and the user record was created in these tables. There seems to be a disconnect between my web and persistence projects.

I have reviewed all of the articles I could find in MySQL however these all appear to be out of date and were of no help. At this point I am now writing a custom membership provider to try and get around these problems but to be honest I'm also considering ditching MySQL due to the problems I have faced trying to get this to work.